# Programmatically importing pictures to Apple Photos and modifying Exif data

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app, python, exif

[[I was suggested to post this here instead of StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54937909/5478086) ]

How do I programmatically import picture files to Apple's Photos app?

The reason for this is that I have 20,000 old pictures. Most are in folders whose names have the data of when the pictures were taken or the file names themselves have the date and time stamps. So the idea is to import the pictures into Photos, but setting the folder/file name as the date and time taken.

Any hints? Thanks! Oh, and I'm doing this in Python.

If I have to move this to SuperUser, please let me know.

Comment: Can you write some code to modify the filenames to match your needs, and then just drag&drop the 20k into Photos?

Comment: PS: Instead of reposting please consider flagging your own question on the original site and have a moderator *move* it to another SE community. Otherwise you end up with two sets of answers.